# JQuery FullCalendar does not show on AJAX page

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get adam shaw's jquery fullcalendar to show up in an ajax content div.
And I seem to get nowhere with this. With my sparse knowledge, I have given up and would
like to turn to experts to help me. Thanks for reading my question.

1. I have 2 web pages - my main page, index.php and my calendar page, calendar.php.

   --------------------------index.php-------------------------

   ```
   var loadedobjects=""
   var rootdomain="http://"+window.location.hostname

   function ajaxpage(url, containerid){
       var page_request = false;
       if (window.XMLHttpRequest) // if Mozilla, Safari etc
           page_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
       else if (window.ActiveXObject){ // if IE
           try {
               page_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
           }
           catch (e){
               try{
                   page_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
               }
               catch (e){}
           }
       }//else if
       else
           return false;
           page_request.onreadystatechange=function(){
           loadpage(page_request, containerid);
       }
       page_request.open('GET', url, true);
       page_request.send(null);
   }


   function loadpage(page_request, containerid){
       if (page_request.readyState == 4 && (page_request.status==200 || window.location.href.indexOf("http")==-1)){
           if (document.getElementById(containerid) != null)
               document.getElementById(containerid).innerHTML=page_request.responseText;
       }
   }
   ```
2. calendar.php has the following:

   The "script" and "link" tags at the top of the page to load the jquery plugins and the
   style sheets and below code:

   --------------------------calendar.php---------------------

   $(document).ready(function() {

   ```
   $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
       header: {
           left: 'prev,next today',
           center: 'title',
           right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
       },

       editable: true,

       events: "<?echo $data_path?>",

       loading: function(bool) {
           if (bool) $('#loading').show();
           else $('#loading').hide();
       }

   });
   ```

   });

   The menu option Class Schedule on index.php make a javascript function call

   javascript:ajaxpage('calendar.php', 'left-content');

   How do I get the page calendar.php to show in div "left-content" of index.php
   upon clicking menu option?

   Any help would be tremendously valuable. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert of PHP but I can see you have one page and in the second you load anoter page with jQuery. First tip is to change from

`$(document).ready(function() {`

to

`$(document).live("click", function(){`

Because calendar.php is loaded dynamically and $(document).ready() doesn't fire because DOM is loaded inside **index.php**. When you change into live jQuery selection will be executed after ajax.

### //Edit

Here you got reference to [jQuery live](http://api.jquery.com/live/). Also [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) function can help you.